# Unicode character in android sms

Tags: android, unicode, sms

In my sms sending application is using a degree symbol(°) in message.  By the using the symbol, the length of the message is reduced to 70 chars (unicode sms) instead of 160 chars.  So my total message's length is 150 chars and it costs 3 sms.  How can i send this message as a normal message.

any solution is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the degree symbol in the GSM alphabet input mode, you will see it correctly on your phone and keep your 160 chars, but the symbol will come through as gibberish or a ? for the one you're sending it to.

If you don't have a particular objection to just typing "degrees" in full, I'd say that would be the fastest and easiest solution.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you.  I will use "degrees" instead of degree symbol. Thanks